# jQuery .css() won’t set the CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason when I use jQuery .css() it won’t change my CSS. I've checked it through several times, and the syntax seems to be right.

I can see that it is running the operation, so the only thing that does not work is the CSS line:

**jQuery:**

```
var document = this;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log("document ready");


jQuery("#buttonrow .button").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    console.log("button clicked");
    if($this.attr("id") == 'redbutton'){
        console.log("red");
        $('#redCheckDiv').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        console.log("blue");
        $('#blueCheckDiv').css('display', 'block');
    }
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" id="buttonrow">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 button" id="bluebutton">
    <div class="blueCheckDiv"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center" id="text-container">
            <p>This is the blue box</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 button" id="redbutton">
    <div class="redCheckDiv"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center" id="text-container">
            <p>this is the red box</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what functionality you want to achieve?

Comment: You are using # id selector, but in your html code attribute is class, so, use class selector., e.g. : $('.redCheckDiv')...

Comment: seems like its the element selector pbm....

Comment: Lol yea, i'm using id selector... Haha, sorry for not realising that before posting.

Comment: It works now, after having fixed the selectors.

Answer (score 6):

So here in your html, 
You have created redcheckdiv and bluecheckdiv as class not as id.
So you haveto use  dot instead of # .
Below is the answer.

```
var document = this;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log("document ready");


  jQuery("#buttonrow .button").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    console.log("button clicked");
    if($this.attr("id") == 'redbutton'){
        console.log("red");
        $('.redCheckDiv').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        console.log("blue");
        $('.blueCheckDiv').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, your selector was invalid, because you selected on an ID, but a class was defined in your markup. This can be easy to do, and hard to spot, even for experienced JavaScript developers.

#### Avoiding pain associated with bad selectors

To debug this sort of issue, use the debugger console. Enter the selector(s) for the problematic area of your code, and hit enter:

```
$('#blueCheckDiv')
```

If you get this result, the selector does not exist on the page.

```
j…y.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#blueCheckDiv"}
```

If your markup exists before your JavaScript does, you may find it’s easiest to build your selectors this way. Enter them into he console to test them, before even adding them to your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code it's working perfectly ( Change Id to class )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonrow .button").click(function() {

        var click_id = $(this).attr("id");

        if (click_id == 'redbutton') {
            console.log("red");
            $('.redCheckDiv').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            console.log("blue");
            $('.blueCheckDiv').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You entered 2 `div`'s with classes in the HTML, but you marked them as `id`'s in the jQuery, here is the correct code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonrow .button").click(function() {

        var click_id = $(this).attr("id");

        if (click_id == 'redbutton') {
            console.log("red");
            $('.redCheckDiv').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            console.log("blue");
            $('.blueCheckDiv').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="buttonrow">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 button" id="bluebutton">
    <div class="blueCheckDiv"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center" id="text-container">
            <p>This is the blue box</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 button" id="redbutton">
    <div class="redCheckDiv"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center" id="text-container">
            <p>this is the red box</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!